# Generated Android apk signed with original google play key is installed as different app

Tags: android, certificate, apk, android-keystore

At the moment, I am extending an app that has been developed by somebody else.

From the client I got the original keystore file that was used to publish the app to the Play Store including the passwords required. I previously gave out test versions that were signed using some dummy key I generated for this purpose.

I am using Eclipse Indigo with ADT for all the packaging and signing.

The strange thing is, that even after creating a signed application package using the *official* key, the older test version using the *dummy* key gets overridden on installation. If I try and install the App from the Play Store, I get a second App on my phone, exactly as if it were signed with a different key.

I tried to

```
keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA | egrep "^\s+MD5|^\s+SHA"
```

on the contents of my own generated apk files and those of the apk file from the Play Store. I get the same hashes on my own file signed with the official key and the file from the Play Store. The file signed with the dummy key results in different hashes, exactly as I would expect it to be.

However, my phone (and the one from my client) treat both apk files from me as one app, and the version from the Play Store as another one.

Is there anything else that identifies an app aside from package name and the key that has been used to sign it? I'm pretty confused right now to be honest. Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: Have you changed the version code???

Comment: No, I didn't change it so far.

Comment: Version code should be changed while releasing the new version of an older app..Then only google play realises that it as an update to the previous one..check that..

Comment: Check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) for that..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even after changing version code and name I still get two seperate apps after installing from Play Store and from my apk file. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the problem. In fact, there wasn't any problem at all despite the one in front of the monitor... The package name in the Play Store had been altered *after* the source code had been copied for me. So there simply was a tiny difference in the package name between my own files and the Play Store. At least I have learned pretty much about determining the fingerprint of an apk file...